# Exercício de Programação C

Tags: c

Fiz uma estrutura em c que recebe : código, idade e estado civil...de alguns usuários...
Como fazer ele contar o numero de solteiros, casados e divorciados....

```
# include<stdio.h>

struct basededasos{
    Int código;
    Int idade;
    char estadocivil[50];
} pessoa[10]

int main(){
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        Printf("Digite código e idade: );
        scanf("%d %d",&pessoa[i].codigo,&pessoa[i].idade);

        Printf("Estado civil: );
        scanf("%s",&pessoa[i].estadocivil);
    }


}
```

Comment: `C` é uma linguagem do tipo sensível a caixa(case sensitivity) ou seja o compilador diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de guardar toda a palavra no membro `estadocivil` use apenas um caractere para representar o que você quer.

Sendo:

- `S` para solteiro;
- `C` para casado;
- `D` para divorciado;

Assim você pode usar uma função `estadoCivilQuantidade` e especificar qual estado civil você quer obter a quantidade no argumento `estadoCivil`, veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 6

typedef struct pessoa {
    int codigo;
    int idade;
    char estadoCivil;
} TPessoa;

int estadoCivilQuantidade(TPessoa pessoas[TAM], char estadoCivil);

int main(void) {
    TPessoa pessoas[TAM];
    pessoas[0].codigo = 1;
    pessoas[0].idade = 22;
    pessoas[0].estadoCivil = 'S';

    pessoas[1].codigo = 2;
    pessoas[1].idade = 43;
    pessoas[1].estadoCivil = 'C';

    pessoas[2].codigo = 3;
    pessoas[2].idade = 19;
    pessoas[2].estadoCivil = 'C';

    pessoas[3].codigo = 4;
    pessoas[3].idade = 22;
    pessoas[3].estadoCivil = 'S';

    pessoas[4].codigo = 5;
    pessoas[4].idade = 26;
    pessoas[4].estadoCivil = 'S';

    pessoas[5].codigo = 6;
    pessoas[5].idade = 32;
    pessoas[5].estadoCivil = 'D';

    int solteirosQuantidade = estadoCivilQuantidade(pessoas, 'S');
    int casadosQuantidade = estadoCivilQuantidade(pessoas, 'C');
    int divorciadosQuantidade = estadoCivilQuantidade(pessoas, 'D');

    printf("Solteiros: %d\n", solteirosQuantidade);
    printf("Casados: %d\n", casadosQuantidade);
    printf("Divorciados: %d\n", divorciadosQuantidade);

    return 0;
}

int estadoCivilQuantidade(TPessoa pessoas[TAM], char estadoCivil) {
    int i, quantidade = 0;
    for (i =0; i < TAM; i++) {
        if (pessoas[i].estadoCivil == estadoCivil) {
            quantidade++;
        }
    }
    return quantidade;
}
```

Saída:

> Solteiros: 3
>   Casados: 2
>   Divorciados: 1

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@drmcarvalho/qtdsolteirocasado).

Answer (score 0):

Use o strcmp para comparar o estado civil, e adicionar +1 ao estado civil correspondente. Assim consegue fazer a contagem que pretende

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

 struct basededasos{
        Int código;
        Int idade;
        char estadocivil[50];
    } pessoa[10]

    int main(){
        int i,solteiro,casado,divorciado;

        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            Printf("Digite código e idade: \n");
            scanf("%d %d",&pessoa[i].codigo,&pessoa[i].idade);

            Printf("Estado civil: \n");
            scanf("%s",&pessoa[i].estadocivil);
            if (strcmmp(pessoa[i].idade,"solteiro")==0)
            solteiro++;
            else 
            if (strcmmp(pessoa[i].idade,"casado")==0)
            casado++;
            else 
            if (strcmmp(pessoa[i].idade,"divorciado")==0)
            divorciado++;
        }


    }
```